# Best way to wrap elment in a technical selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a project, I often manipulate the DOM by adding / replacing elements from an HTML string :

```
$("#myDiv").html("<ul><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></ul><p>This is a list</p>");
```

I would like to wrap those in "something with a technical id attached" so that my jQuery selectors can be targetted to these specific fragmeents of the page.

Something like that :

```
var techId = ...; 
$("#myDiv").html(wrap(techId, "<ul id="myList"><li>foo</li><li>bar</li></ul><p>This is a list</p>"));
$(document).on("click", "#"+techId+" #myList", function(event){
    alert("List clicked");
});
```

What should be the content of the "wrap" function knowing that the wrapper cannot have any visual impact one the page, in any situation.

Calling .remove() on the wrapper should remove the wrapped element but there should be a way of removing the wrapper without modifying the elements inside (at the expense of breaking the selectors).

Comment: Did you have a look at `.wrap()` and `.unwrap()`? http://api.jquery.com/wrap/, http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/ (`.wrapAll`  might be more suitable even: http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Comment: It sure seems do to the trick :)
Should I wrap in a div, a span or another elment I would have forgotten ?

Comment: It depends on you, but remember it's not good to put block elements inside inline one (Eg: <div><span>...</span></div> is proper, while <span><div>...</div></span> is not - well, it will work, but it is always good to make things the right way ;))